# Why does the concentration gradient of one ion represent the entire cell in the equilibrium potential of an ion?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, cell-membrane

The Nernst equation for the equilibrium potential of an ion(in this case potassium),
$$E_{eq,K^+} = \frac{RT}{zF} \ln \frac{[K^+]_{o}}{[K^+]_{i}}$$
includes the ratio of the concentration of *that specific ion* outside of the membrane to the concentration inside. If this is for calculating the diffusional force, why does it ignore other ions? Wouldn't the concentration of other ions inside and outside of the cell also affect this ratio?

For example, some ion might be more abundant inside the membrane than the outside, but some other particle might be more abundant outside, thus creating no diffusional force. However, in the equation this will be taken as if this does indeed generate a force, since it only takes into account the ion more abundant inside.

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange. [Cross-posting](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/166592/why-is-only-one-type-of-ion-relevant-in-the-nernst-equation-for-an-ions-equilib) is generally not desired on StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

Just add up everything of interest. For example, you can include sodium as
[image]

which gives you

[image]

chlorides, and everything else could be further added in a similar fashion, although likely to diminishing effects. These equations and numbers are from page 107-108 of [From Neuron to Brain](https://learninglink.oup.com/access/nicholls-fntb-5e).